# What is the simplest way to set up a query form online to then plug into Access?

Tags: web-services, ms-access

I want to experiment with putting a form on a website. Then take the answers from the filled form and viewing those answers in Access to be linked directly into a db.
Any ideas?  How do I create the form, ASP, html?  I know connection using ODBC from ASP to Access can work - I need more info around the issue generally.. alternatives etc.

Thanks

Comment: You won't be using Access, just Jet, which is the default db engine for an Access application. If you mean "Access" and not just "Jet" (i.e., you're using your "Access" database as nothing but a set of data tables), then it's a completely different question.

Comment: But if they are using Access2007's new database format then they will be using the Access Data Engine (note "Access") or ACE for short. Hopefully they are because Jet was deprecated years ago, ACE is the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very broad question, but your easiest method would be to do the following.

Using Visual Web Developer Express (Or full Visual Studio if you have it).  Create a web applciation using ASP.NET and your language of choice.

Add the Access Database to the website in the App_Data folder of the project, and depending on your specific needs, from here you can use a lot of the drag-drop items to build the page up.

A few notes.

1. Using the drag and drop items are great for rapidly putting up a site, but do not follow best practices.
2. 4guysfromrolla.com is a great reference for the how-to's on the ASP.NET side of things
3. Access IS NOT necessarily the best choice for a database engine for a website...but can work.

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget that you can use a parameter query in Access and update that, it is more secure.